# Attempting to load out of an FXML scene into an FX scene

Tags: java, javafx

I made a bit of a mess when coding my program however do not have time to fix it before submission. My program opens up to a 3D molecule viewer for Water, Methane and Methyl, this is done without FXML and simply creates panes, borders, canvas and cameras which you can manipulate to view 360 around the molecule. One button on my side bar switches into an FXML Gui for a chemistry database, in which I want to display my SQL data.

However, once the scene has been switched I cannot switch back. I have attempted to reference the main class in the original starting .java through the FXMLController however it simply says that Handler method is not assesable, I add the @FXML and again nothing fixes. So Instead I attempted to make a public method which calls the main from the same class, this would work other than the fact that it now says that the handler method is not found.

I have searched high and low and cannot seem to find an answer. I am very new to java and javafx and would love to see this project through to the end.(Especially because completing this one simple(or not so apparently) function will complete my project bar loading the SQL database inside the GUI.

I will post a link to the FXML code and the class in which the main class is found.

Thanks

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/753797aeca8f12c8086628b740525625 --> FXMLDocument

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/60c58df1268aa5adeafca8faabf14c4c --> Class that has main(String[] args)

Comment: Include your code directly in your question.  If the external links ever go stale, your question will be of no value to future readers.

Comment: Don't post links to code. Firstly, it's highly unlikely anyone is going to go through ~700 lines of code to try to understand the issue. Secondly, and more importantly, if the pages to which the links point change or are removed, then the question becomes of no use to other users of this site. Create a simple version of what you have that demonstrates the problem, which you should be able to do in just a few lines of code, and post that code in your question so that others can actually run it and see the whole problem. Read this: [MCVE] for a complete description of how to present the problem.